# How to customize image size for card in vue bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am working on a NuxtJS project, with BootstrapVue as front-end framework. I am trying to edit the size of an image inserted inside the title of a card, with the following code:

```
<b-card
          bg-variant="primary"
          text-variant="white"
          img-alt="Image"
          img-src="~/assets/images/house.png"
          header="The house"
          class="text-center position-relative"
        >
          <b-card-text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </b-card-text>
          <b-button variant="primary" class="paragraph stretched-link"
            >Click here</b-button
          >
        </b-card>
```

Does anyone know if is possible to customize the style of the image through the b-card properties (without CSS)? The documentation did not helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `img-height` and `img-width` to provide the image size inside the card, they accepts a string or a number as values :

```
<b-card
          bg-variant="primary"
          text-variant="white"
          img-alt="Image"
          img-src="~/assets/images/house.png"
          img-height="200"
          img-width="200"
          header="The house"
          class="text-center position-relative"
        >
```

Comment: Hi Boussadjrai, thanks for your answer. Yours is definatelly a good approach! but unfortuntatelly is not flexible enough in order to position the image as I am trying to. I think I will just manipulate it through SCSS. Thanks anyway!

Comment: there're other props like `img-top` `img-start`, check the whole list of `img-*` here https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/card#comp-ref-b-card